# How to delete event listener without external function

Tags: javascript, html, web

Got the real dilemma. I have an init function which has lots of parameters inside which are depended on each other and can't be remove outside, an array of elements and added to each a click event listener. This event listener checks if the clicked element is a certain element then remove the click listener from all elements in the array. The promblem is I have to use an anonimus function in the event listener due to the internal parameters of the init function, but to delete an event listener I must pass the same function in removeEventListener so it must be named function and I can't get solution for this.

The approximate logic:

```
let init = () =>{

  //some internal parameters here and logic

  for (let i = 0; i < elArr.length; i++) {

    elArr[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
        if (event.target.style.background ===
            elArr[pickedElement].style.background) {

            //Not working (can't define the param as a separate function due 
            //to params of this function can't be passed to there)
            for (let i = 0; i < elArr.length; i++)
                elArr[i].removeEventListener("click", event);

        } else {
            event.target.style.background = bgColor;
        }
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you can declare the named function *inside* of the init function, so it'll still have access to all of the internal variables and such.

```
let init = () => {
  //some internal parameters here and logic

  let bgCheckListener = event => {
    if (
      event.target.style.background ===
      elArr[pickedElement].style.background
    ) {
      elArr.forEach(el => {
        el.removeEventListener("click", bgCheckListener)
      })
    } else {
      event.target.style.background = bgColor
    }
  }

  elArr.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("click", bgCheckListener)
  })
}
```

Comment: You're a genius! Want to be your apprentice! Is it a good practice to declare a function inside an another?

Comment: Should be fine. First-class functions are a luxury in JS, so abuse them ;)

Answer (score 1):

`[Removed original answer as jquery is not applicable]`

You can simply replace the event

Instead of removing the event listener replace the event listener on the element using

```
elArr[i].onClick = function() { };
```

Comment: I need to use vanila js

Comment: @fxvlad I've updated my answer, sorry I missed that!

Comment: not working for me, I'm guessing it only works if you assigned it like that. also I think it's onclick